# Node.js does multer with diskStorage create a folder if it doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, multer

I have a small app that receives via POST a file and stores it in a specific folder.

I know that this line:

```
const multer = multer({ dest: ‘media' })
```

(of course with some more code, where I use the multer.single('somefilename')) will create a new folder named media if it doesn't exist already.

But I want to be able to control the name given to the file and some other stuff, so I'm using it with diskStorage instead:

```
const x = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, 'media')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
})

const multer = multer({ storage: x })
```

(there's some more code of course with multer.single('somefilename'))

It works fine when the folder 'media' already exists, but doesn't create it if it doesn't - is it supposed to, or only the simpler multer can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't create the folder, they warn that in the official [doc](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#storage):

> Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing
> destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make
> sure that the directory is created for you.

Below is an example of how to create the entire path, but exist many alternatives:

```
const path = require("path");
const shell = require('shelljs');

const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', "uploads");
shell.mkdir('-p', fullPath);
```

---

As @robertklep suggest, please consider:   **fs.mkdir()**  instead of shell:

```
fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'test'), { recursive: true })
```

Comment: Why use a shell when `fs.mkdir()` can recursively create directories?